# ObservableCollection only updating on Map Zoom and Move events not adding to Collection!

Tags: windows-phone-7, observablecollection

I have an issue with a collection that I have bound.  I have a manual refresh button that pulls some moving pushpins from the server.  The server is moving the pins itself.  After processing I delete the existing collection and re add it to the Observable Collection. This code works and I have verififed that the contents have been update however the pins only "update" (move on the map) if a Zoom or move of the map has happened!

My class is as follows...

```
public class MapData : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisedPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private GeoCoordinate mapCenter = new GeoCoordinate(50, -1);

        public GeoCoordinate MapCenter
        {
            get { return this.mapCenter; }
            set
            {
                if (this.mapCenter == value) return;
                this.mapCenter = value;
                this.RaisedPropertyChanged("MapCenter");
            }
        }

        private double zoom = 7.0;
        public double Zoom
        {
            get { return this.zoom; }
            set
            {
                if (this.zoom == value) return;
                this.zoom = value;
                this.RaisedPropertyChanged("Zoom");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Plane> pins = new ObservableCollection<Plane>() { 

        };

        public ObservableCollection<Plane> Pins
        {
            get { return pins; }
        }

        public void RemovePoints()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < pins.Count; i++)
            {
                pins.RemoveAt(i);
            }
            pins.Clear();
            this.RaisedPropertyChanged("Location");
        }

       public void AddPoints(List<Plane> Planelist)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < Planelist.Count; i++) 
            {
                pins.Add(Planelist[i]);
            }

        }



        private Plane selectedPin;
        public Plane SelectedPin
        {
            get {
                return this.selectedPin;
            }
            set
            {
                if (this.selectedPin == value) return;
                this.selectedPin = value;
                this.RaisedPropertyChanged("SelectedPin");

            }
        }

        private LocationCollection routePoints = new LocationCollection();
        public LocationCollection RoutePoints
        {
            get { return routePoints; }
        }

    }
```

And it is bound using the following...

```
<my:MapItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Pins}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PushedMe}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with Microsoft it appears that the device will cache URL's and that is actually my issue!  Forced no-cache on the server side and issue fixed!